# GCC undefined reference to main

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, sdl-2

I face a strange behaviour with gcc :
When I try to compile using the makefile I wrote, I get few errors, which I don't get when I compile using single command line ...

Here are my files :

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "src/system/engine.h"

int main(void){
    Engine engine;
    memset(&engine, 0, sizeof(Engine));

    if (InitEngine(&engine) != 0){
        return 1;
    }

    FreeEngine(&engine);
    return 0;
}
```

engine.h

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

typedef struct {
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Window   *window;
} Engine;


int InitEngine(Engine *engine);
void FreeEngine (Engine *engine);

#endif
```

engine.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "src/system/engine.h"

int InitEngine(Engine *engine) {
    return 0;
}

void FreeEngine(Engine *engine) {
}
```

makefile

```
ROOT = $(shell pwd)
SOURCES_DIR := $(ROOT)/src
OBJECTS_DIR := $(ROOT)/obj

CC = gcc

PROJECT = game
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SOURCES_DIR) -name '*.c' -type f)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

INCLUDES       := $(ROOT) /usr/includes/SDL2
INCLUDES_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I ,$(INCLUDES))

CFLAGS  := -Wall -D_REENTRANT
LDFLAGS := -lSDL2

ALL: clean $(PROJECT)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)

$(PROJECT): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) 

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@  $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES_FLAGS)
```

Running `make` produce the following output (sorry for french output) :

```
rm -f /home/antoine/work/Game/src/system/engine.o /home/antoine/work/Game/src/main.o
gcc -c /home/antoine/work/Game/src/system/engine.c -o /home/antoine/work/Game/src/system/engine.o  -Wall -D_REENTRANT -I /home/antoine/work/Game -I /usr/includes/SDL2
gcc -c /home/antoine/work/Game/src/system/engine.c -o /home/antoine/work/Game/src/main.o  -Wall -D_REENTRANT -I /home/antoine/work/Game -I /usr/includes/SDL2
gcc /home/antoine/work/Game/src/system/engine.o /home/antoine/work/Game/src/main.o -o game -lSDL2 
/usr/bin/ld : /home/antoine/work/Game/src/main.o : dans la fonction « InitEngine » :
engine.c:(.text+0x0) : définitions multiples de « InitEngine »; /home/antoine/work/Game/src/system/engine.o:engine.c:(.text+0x0) : défini pour la première fois ici
/usr/bin/ld : /home/antoine/work/Game/src/main.o : dans la fonction « FreeEngine » :
engine.c:(.text+0xf) : définitions multiples de « FreeEngine »; /home/antoine/work/Game/src/system/engine.o:engine.c:(.text+0xf) : défini pour la première fois ici
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/../../../../lib64/crt1.o : dans la fonction « _start » :
(.text+0x1b) : référence indéfinie vers « main »
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné le statut de sortie 1
make: *** [makefile:24: game] Error 1
```

But when I try to compile all in one command, with :
`gcc -I/home/antoine/work/Game -I/usr/includes/SDL2 -lSDL2 /home/antoine/work/Game/src/system/engine.c /home/antoine/work/Game/src/main.c -o game`

It does not throw any error, and does work like a charm ...

I'm missing something for sure, which may be in the makefile (as the same code produce different output), but to be honest, I would appreciate another point of view ...

Comment: There are three calls to gcc in there, two object-building, one exe-building. Do you see that both of the former compile `engine.c`, and none compiles `main.c`?

Comment: Oh got it thanks, it try to compile engine.c instead of main.c
Thanks for pointing me that out ;)

Comment: Note that your `$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)` rule means that if either source file changes, both object files will be recompiled.  If you change the header, neither object file will be compiled.  You want `game.o` to be recompiled if you change `game.c`; you want `main.o` to be recompiled if you change `main.c`; you want both to be recompiled if you change `game.h`.  You could probably use two rules: `game.o: game.h` and `main.o: game.h` and let the default (implicit) rules build the object files.  Make can deduce that `game.o` depends on `game.c` and you don't need to tell it that.

Comment: There are other variants, such as `$(OBJECTS): game.h` with no recipe after it.  That'll run the default C compilation.

Comment: Don't be afraid to turn my comment -- and your findings coming from that -- into your own answer. You're not "stealing rep". I just made a drive-by comment about what I saw in the log. If you turn that into a formulated answer including the fix, you're welcome to the upvotes.